# Bootstrap Date picker - "todayHighlight:true" not working

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap - date picker (js and css).

Following is the code, unable to figure out the error. Date component gets displayed but any rules that are written inside the script is not getting executed. some listed below.

```
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
startDate: -7,
endDate: +3,
todayHighlight: true
```

FULL CODE:

```
<script>
$('#sandbox-container.input-group.date').datepicker({
todayHighlight: true
});
</script>

<div id="sandbox-container" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="form-control ">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use html **data attributes** or add it from datepicker **javascript** properties. Don't mixup both.

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/hous9y5L/246/**

You forgot the double quotes for **startDate** and **endDate**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sandbox-container" class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control ">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#sandbox-container.input-group.date').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "-7d",
    endDate: "+3d"
});
```

or you can do this way:

**Fiddle** : **http://jsfiddle.net/hous9y5L/248/**

```
<div id="sandbox-container" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-start-date="-7d" data-date-end-date="+3d" data-date-today-highlight="true">
  <input type="text" class="form-control ">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but other rules are not working :(

Comment: Updated the answer if you are looking for previous 7 days to next 3 days

Answer (score 0):

You have both `data-provide="datepicker"` and `$('#sandbox-container.input-group.date').datepicker();` in the same html page. That's redundant.

Try

```
$('#sandbox-container.input-group.date').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
});
```

Or (shouldn't use both)

```
<div id="sandbox-container" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-today-highlight>
    Your content here
</div>
```

Also check the browser console for other errors, like:
`startDate` must be `"-7d"` instead of `-7`,
`endDate` must be `"+3d"` instead of `+3`

```
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
startDate: "-7d",
endDate: "+3d",
todayHighlight: true
```