# Django Bootstrap Date Picker default value / todayBtn problem

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I created a Date Picker using Django and Bootstrap. When clicking on the calendar field on the right of the input field, however, the calendar jumps to a default of: `06/Fr/yyyy`. I tried setting the `todayBtn` attribute to True but that produced an error. Example can be seen on the following image:

[image]

My models.py:

```
class TimeInterval(models.Model):
    time_interval = models.DateField()
```

forms.py:

```
from .models import TimeInterval
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput

class TimeIntervalForm(forms.ModelForm):

    date = forms.DateField(
        widget=DatePickerInput(
                options={
                    "format": "mm/dd/yyyy",
                    # "todayHighlight": True,
                    # "todayBtn": True,
                }
            )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = TimeInterval
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
def datepicker_form_view(request):
    return render(request, "datepicker_form.html", {
        "time_interval_form": TimeIntervalForm(),
    })
```

And my HTML file:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}

<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form time_interval_form %}
    {{time_interval_form.media }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I came across [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400606/bootstrap-date-picker-todayhighlighttrue-not-working) about the `todayHighlight` attribute but there the OP used JavaScript/jQuery, hence it was advised that he added that attribute using a jQuery select. I feel that in my case, expanding the HTML code with a `<script>` section and a jQuery selection just to have that one attribute working is an overkill - there must be a more convenient way to go about this that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
date = forms.DateTimeField(error_messages={'invalid': 'Wrong date.'},
                       required=False, widget=DateInput(attrs={
                               'class': 'datepicker form-control input-sm ',
                               'data-trigger': 'focus'}))
```

or

```
date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False,
                       widget=DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'},
                                        format=('%Y-%m-%d')))
```